# iterating 2D heterogeneous array groovy

Tags: multidimensional-array, groovy

I have particular case where i am getting following data as 2D array in batches. My consumer service needs to execute few logic on each batch. how can i iterate over following array to access 1st and 3rd value of each subarray

```
[["TCA","VALID","7cb3b016-0f53-40fc-a6ff-55d2fd7613","38216552696060"], ["TCA","VALID","8540347a-0f6e-4f8c-8e5b-dcadfc8069","36116552696114"], ["TCA","VALID","a2e7a765-3be0-4d0f-9974-ee8708dc44","35716552696108"], ["TCA","VALID","a7ec0957-4787-4bf7-942f-e78b171322","32216552696102"], ["TCA","VALID","adf4a75f-b725-4809-a0b8-8923d1a2a2","33316552696037"]]
```

I need to extract "TCA" and "38216552696060" like value for each subarray apply logic on it then move to next subarray until the batch is done.

i tried this but it gives collection of first element of all subarray.

```
println queue.take()*.head()
```

i am new to groovy and looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
queue.each{ e->
    println e[0] //--> should print first element for each subarray
    println e[3] //--> should print fourth element for each subarray
    //any other logic ...
}
```

or with default variable name - `it`

```
queue.each{
    println it[0] //--> should print first element for each subarray
    println it[3] //--> should print fourth element for each subarray
    //any other logic ...
}
```

or with for:

```
for(e in queue) {
    println e[0] //--> should print first element for each subarray
    println e[3] //--> should print fourth element for each subarray
    //any other logic ...
}
```

or classic for

```
for(int i=0; i<queue.size(); i++){
    println queue[i][0] //--> should print first element for each subarray
    println queue[i][3] //--> should print fourth element for each subarray
    //any other logic ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
println queue*.getAt([0, -1])
```

Should just get the first and last of each entry